# Is it possible to have a MySQL SELECT statement contain two functions?

Tags: mysql

A column in a database contains IP addresses in hexadecimal format.

I want to select that column and have the output converted back into the conventional IP address format.

There are two steps in the conversion process which are -

```
SELECT CONV('IPAddr', 16, 10) FROM event;

>3362028388
>... plus plenty more addresses
```

then

```
INET_NTOA (3362028388)

>200.100.123.100
```

The problems for me are as follows:

1. I want to cobine this functionality into a single statement.
2. The INET_NTOA command needs to work by containing the column name instead of a single IP. I understand that a column name can be put in place of an IP address, however, in its normal state the column contains hex values so this doesn't work.

Would it be possible to have the output of the converion held in a variable and have the INET_NTOA command convert the addresses from the variable?

Comment: 'IPAddr' is a string, not a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put functions into functions as well ;)

```
SELECT INET_NTOA(CONV(IPAddr, 16, 10)) FROM event;
```

And as Strawberry already mentionend, with the single-quotes it's a string, not a column.